# Data and array formatting help (nodejs)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, object

I have four input arrays that all correspond with one output array like so:

```
var arr1 = [.84, .01, .95, 1, .22, .453, .194, .43];
var arr2 = [.54, .09, .10, 0, .76, .12, .41, .99];
var arr3 = [1, .26, .90, .65, .88, .33, .854, .414];
var arr4 = [.65, .84, .184, .81, .04, .09, 0, .46];

var output = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
```

arr1, arr2, arr3, and arr4 are the input arrays and output is the output array. I need to be able to format this data so that each corresponding element of the input arrays are put into one array and the corresponding element in the output array is put in another array, like so:

```
var new = [{input: [.84, .54, 1, .65], output: [1]}, {input: [.01, .09, .26, .84], output: [0]}, ... {input: [.43, .99, .414, .46], output: [1]}];
```

All arrays are the same length (the above are only examples). I am using Node.js; all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably some more performant ways to do this, but I'd just use a simple for loop.

```
var arr1 = [.84, .01, .95, 1, .22, .453, .194, .43];
var arr2 = [.54, .09, .10, 0, .76, .12, .41, .99];
var arr3 = [1, .26, .90, .65, .88, .33, .854, .414];
var arr4 = [.65, .84, .184, .81, .04, .09, 0, .46];

var output = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];
var new = [];

for (var i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
  var input = [arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i], arr4[i]];
  var output = [output[i]];

  new.push({input: input, output: output});
}
```

This would give you your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect time to use some functional programming.  I prefer lodash.js.

```
var arr1 = [.84, .01, .95, 1, .22, .453, .194, .43];
var arr2 = [.54, .09, .10, 0, .76, .12, .41, .99];
var arr3 = [1, .26, .90, .65, .88, .33, .854, .414];
var arr4 = [.65, .84, .184, .81, .04, .09, 0, .46];

var output = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];

_(_.zip(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)).zip(output);
```

Take a look at [the documentation](https://lodash.com/docs#zip) for _.zip, as it has a better explanation and more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit cleaner implementation than below, uses a bit of FP but no need for lodash. :)

```
var arr1 = [.84, .01, .95, 1, .22, .453, .194, .43];
var arr2 = [.54, .09, .10, 0, .76, .12, .41, .99];
var arr3 = [1, .26, .90, .65, .88, .33, .854, .414];
var arr4 = [.65, .84, .184, .81, .04, .09, 0, .46];

var output = [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1];

var transformed = output.map(function(v, i) {
  return {
    input: [arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i], arr4[i]],
    output: [v]
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var resultsArray = []
for(var i =0; i < output.length; i++){
    var currentRound = {input:[ arr1[i], arr2[i], arr3[i], arr4[i]], output: output[i]}
    resultsArray.push(currentRound)
}
```

that should do what you want

edit: super late to the party.